# Tikz-cd diagram arrow passing under a node - not crossing it

Tags: arrows, nodes, tikz-cd

I'm drawing some commutative diagrams, and some of my diagonal arrows are crossing nodes on their way. 
I would like to have a sort of "crossing under", to force the arrow not to show while crossing the node.

I copy the code here:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
%first row
A \ar[rr] \ar[dd] \ar[dr]
& 
& B \ar[dd] \ar[dr]
& 
\\
%second row
& E \ar[rr] \ar[dd]
& 
& F \ar[dd]
\\
%third row
C \ar[rr] \ar[dr] \ar[uurr]
& 
& D \ar[dr]
& 
\\
%forth row
& G \ar[rr] \ar[uurr]
& 
& H
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

As you can see, it is very unelegant! It would be nicer if the arrows "interrupted" and started again after the node.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Splitting into multiple arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
%first row
A \ar[rr] \ar[dd] \ar[dr]
& 
& B \ar[dd] \ar[dr]  \ar[from=dl]
& 
\\
%second row
& E \ar[rr] \ar[dd] \ar[-,dl]
& 
& F \ar[dd]
\\
%third row
C \ar[rr] \ar[dr]
& 
& D \ar[dr] \ar[ur]
& 
\\
%forth row
& G \ar[rr] \ar[-,ur]
& 
& H
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Avoiding the nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
%first row
A \ar[rr] \ar[dd] 
& 
& B \ar[dd] \ar[dr] \ar[from=ddll,bend left=30]
& 
\\
%second row
& E \ar[rr] \ar[dd] \ar[from=ul,crossing over]
& 
& F \ar[dd]
\\
%third row
C \ar[rr] \ar[dr] 
& 
& D \ar[dr]
& 
\\
%forth row
& G \ar[rr] \ar[from=uurr,bend left=30,crossing over]
& 
& H
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for both suggestions, but my diagrams are growing more an more complicated, so I prefer to avoid adding or bending arrows. Thank you again!

Comment: Do you have a modification where the arrows go from $B \to C$ and $F\to G$ instead, and the arrow $E\to G$ crosses over the arrow $C\to D$?

Answer (score 7):

Just for fun: an attempt to give a 3D impression.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{contour}
\contourlength{1pt}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture={
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
 \draw[->] (C) -- (B);
\end{scope}
 \draw[preaction={draw,line width=2.4pt,white},->] (G) -- (F);
}]
%first row
A \ar[rr] \ar[dd] \ar[dr]
& 
& |[alias=B]| B \ar[dd] \ar[dr]
& 
\\
%second row
& \contour{white}{$E$} \ar[rr] \ar[dd]
& 
&|[alias=F]| F \ar[dd]
\\
%third row
|[alias=C]| C \ar[rr] \ar[dr] %\ar[uurr]
& 
& D \ar[dr]
& 
\\
%forth row
& |[alias=G]| G \ar[rr] %\ar[uurr]
& 
& H
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, that is really nice. I'm so sorry my diagrams are getting too involuted for that! Thank you, I sincerely appreciated the effort!

Comment: @BarbaraGiunti Honestly I think you should accept the answer by user190633. The currently accepted answer is very fragile. Think of newcomers who may think that the accepted answer may be the "best" one. Of course, this is just my opinion, and you can do what you want.

Comment: I think you're right, it was working for me, so I didn't notice the problem either. Thanks for the suggestions, I'm a newcomer myself!

Answer (score 6):

This does what you want:

```
\documentclass[pdf]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[ 
\begin{tikzcd}
%first row
A \ar[rr] \ar[dd] \ar[dr]
&
& B \ar[dd] \ar[dr]
&
\\
%second row
& E \ar[rr] \ar[dd]
&
& F \ar[dd]
\\
%third row
C \ar[rr] \ar[dr] \ar[uurr, "\textstyle E" description]
&
& D \ar[dr]
&
\\
%forth row
& G \ar[rr] \ar[uurr, "\textstyle D" description]
&
& H
\end{tikzcd}
    \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I wanted!

Comment: This is very fragile. Replace e.g. `B` by `\displaystyle\int_0^1`.

Comment: @marmot: ??? I see no problem on compiling.

Comment: @Bernard Really? How does the bottom the E look like when you compile it? I get a fragment of the E that lies underneath on my just updated TeXLive2019 distribution when compiling this with `pdflatex` and `B` replaced by `\displaystyle\int_0^1`. If you give things some reduced opacity by saying `\begin{tikzcd}[opacity=0.5] ...` you understand why.

Comment: @marmot: I hadn't noticed it  – I must say I didn't zoom out. A workaround seems to replace $E$ and $D$ (the nodes, not the ‘descriptions’) with `\phantom{E/D}` – unless you find out another problem with this way. I'll update the code in a moment, with some improvements.

Comment: What if I want to label the arrow $C\to B$ in this case? If I add ````near start```` then the label on $E$ also moves.

Comment: @AGlearner: In this case, I would  make E a real node in the diagram, and would make a labelled ‘arrow’ without arrow tip between C and E, and a second unlabelled arrow with an arrow tip between E and B.